# Algorithmically generating the syntax of math equations

Tags: editors, automation, auto-completion, environment-variables

Is there a way to algorithmically write equation syntax in latex?? Suppose I want to write the N-point DFT matrix in an equation, then is it possible if i specify what each entry of NxN matrix will be in form of two variables, m and n.

This would mean if I can specify value of N somewhere, then the code for NxN DFT matrix would be generated for that fixed n? I understand this needs to be done outside conventional latex editors.

Example:
Suppose in one tutorial, I want to insert a 5x5 identity matrix, so i will use pmatrix option and then manually insert 25 values, however, if next day, I want to show 3x3 matrix, then i will have to manually delete 16 entries.
But note that here the parameters 5 and 3 completely specify what code i am going to write, so is there something intelligent that can generate the code for the identity matrix automatically once i specify the parameter?

Thanks

Comment: probably the answer is yes but it's not clear what you want, I assume you mean something [like this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/png/e05e8a1703420671b7ec9a7b245fa3280bd5cc33) for a fixed n without the dots, but do you want it written with the the exponents multiplied out or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I want to know if this can be done, for example, I have to frequently type tutorial answers and many times the pattern is same and i just need to change constant value and this change propagates through all the formula in the solution, is it possible for the changes to be computed the way software does and modify the equation entries accordingly, for example if my constant is 6, i want to print x=6 while if it is 7, i want to print x=7, much like c++ but in latex code

Comment: as I say the answer is probably yes but your question isn't clear enough. I have no idea what result you want to display do you want to display  ² or some computed numerical approximation to that or what? your question would be a lot clearer if you showed a sample "by hand" matrix and a sample input that you wish to use to generate the matrix that you show,

Comment: Just use LuaTeX and code it in Lua (you have to learn Lua however). Some other alternatives are Python and expl3.

Comment: The [xfp](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp) package can help...

Comment: If you want an easy-to-change solution, you can look at `LuaLaTeX`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

You define suitable functions as shown, where `#1` and `#2` denote the row and column index respectively. Here `expl3` syntax is used to define a couple of them, but you can use whatever you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\generatematrix}{O{p}mm}
 {% #1 = optional delimiters, default p
  % #2 = function
  % #3 = matrix size
  \begin{#1matrix}
  \kutsit_generatematrix:nn { #2 } { #3 }
  \end{#1matrix}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definefunction}{mm}
 {% #1 = function name
  % #2 = action
  \kutsit_generatematrix_function:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__kutsit_generatematrix_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kutsit_generatematrix:nn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__kutsit_generatematrix_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {% ##1 is the row index
    \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
     {% ####1 is the column index
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__kutsit_generatematrix_body_tl
       {
        \use:c { kutsit_generatematrix_#1:nn } { ##1 } { ####1 }
       }
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__kutsit_generatematrix_body_tl
       {
        \int_compare:nTF { ####1 = #2 } { \exp_not:N \\ } { & }
       }
     }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l__kutsit_generatematrix_body_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kutsit_generatematrix_function:nn
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cn { kutsit_generatematrix_#1:nn } { #2 }
 }


\definefunction{identity}{ \int_compare:nTF { #1 = #2 } { 1 } { 0 } }
\definefunction{hilbert}{ \frac{1}{\int_eval:n { #1 + #2 } } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\generatematrix{identity}{3}\quad
\generatematrix[b]{identity}{5}
\]

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\generatematrix{hilbert}{4}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]