# Procedural matrices in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, physics

Is there a way to typeset a tikz matrix procedurally instead of manually?
i.e. here's a MWE of a 4x4 identity matrix:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes] {
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a macro/command that will automatically generate this but for any dimension `n`. The above case would be of course for `n=4`.

Is this possible? I thought about using the `physics` package's `\imat` command, but this gives the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options

l.9                     \imat{4}

?
! Emergency stop.
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624829/algorithmically-generating-the-syntax-of-math-equations

Comment: It's probably the right approach, but I get a "! Missing $ inserted" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you will be interested in `nicematrix`. This environment provides a command `\pAutoNiceMatrix` to construct matrices with a Tikz node under each cell of the matrix (however, these matrices are *not* arrays of `tikz-matrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Identity}{O{}m}
{\pAutoNiceMatrix[#1]{#2-#2}{\ifthenelse{\arabic{iRow}=\arabic{jCol}}{1}{0}}}

\bigskip
$\Identity{3}$

\bigskip
$\Identity[name=A]{4}$

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw (A-2-2) circle (5pt) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!